# Ansible task fail when running script command

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

When executing a playbook with the following command I get a failed with a `Could not find or access '/opt/ansible-automation-platform-setup-bundle-2.4-1.4-x86_64/setup.sh' on the Ansible Controller.\nIf you are using a module and expect the file to exist on the remote, see the remote_src option`

`ansible-playbook playbooks/install_aap_platform.yml -f 10 -vvv --private-key $ID_RSA -u ec2-user -i installer_node`

This is the ansible playbook:

```
- name: install ansible
  hosts: installnode
  become: yes
  become_user: ansible
  gather_facts: yes
  tasks:
  - name: populate /etc/hosts file
    ansible.builtin.shell: |
      cat {{ lookup('env', 'ANSIBLE_INSTALLER_LOCATION') }}/inventory | grep ".med.ds.osd.mil*" | awk '{print $1}' > test.txt
      for i in $(cat test.txt); do
        echo $i
        if grep -q "$(echo "$i")" /etc/hosts ; then
          echo "hostname $host_name already in hosts file"
        else
          echo $(echo $i |  cut -d'.' -f1 | sed 's/ip-//' | sed 's/-/./g')" $i" >> /etc/hosts
        fi
      done
      cat /etc/hosts
    become: yes
    become_user: root
  - name: Run installer script
    become: yes
    become_user: ansible
    ansible.builtin.script:
      cmd: /opt/ansible-automation-platform-setup-bundle-2.4-1.4-x86_64/setup.sh
    environment:
      ANSIBLE_BECOME_METHOD: 'sudo'
      ANSIBLE_BECOME: True
      ANSIBLE_HOST_KEY_CHECKING: False
    register: out
    ignore_errors: yes
  - name: print output
    debug:
      msg: "{{ out.stdout }}"
```

`populate /etc/hosts file` works without any issue, it is the task `Run installer script` that fails.

The task fails because it is not able to reach the file /opt/ansible-automation-platform-setup-bundle-2.4-1.4-x86_64/setup.sh, but if I ssh into the host and paste `/opt/ansible-automation-platform-setup-bundle-2.4-1.4-x86_64/setup.sh` and press enter, it works right away.

The script does not seem to be the issue, the folder /opt is owned by root, but the folder ansible-automation-platform-setup-bundle-2.4-1.4-x86_64/ is owned by the user ansible.
I know that the become_user works because I used it in a previous task to upload files to the host system without any issues.

Comment: You are able to run the script from the `ansible` user, right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that the [`script` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/script_module.html) copies a *local* script to the *remote* machine. When you have:

```
    ansible.builtin.script:
      cmd: /opt/ansible-automation-platform-setup-bundle-2.4-1.4-x86_64/setup.sh
```

That means it's going to look for `/opt/ansible-automation-platform-setup-bundle-2.4-1.4-x86_64/setup.sh` on the local (control) host, not on the host that is the target of the play. If the script already exists in the remote location, you should be using the `command` module instead:

```
    ansible.builtin.command:
      cmd: /opt/ansible-automation-platform-setup-bundle-2.4-1.4-x86_64/setup.sh
```

---

Unrelated to your question, but in `populate /etc/hosts file` you don't need either `cat` or `grep`; you can write:

```
awk '/.med.ds.osd.mil/ {print $1}' {{ lookup('env', 'ANSIBLE_INSTALLER_LOCATION') }}/inventory > test.txt
```

...and honestly, you could probably replace the entire script with an Ansible loop and the `lineinfile` module.

Comment: thank you very much, that helped, but I had to scrap the installation of aap via ansible because of a "double" assume role that was not usable by ansible. I ended up using sshpass and run an ssh command to install aap. 
I will put the changes in the cat/grep command as per suggestion.Thank you !